# Simlink to Mayavi package into a virtualenv (MAC OSX)

Tags: python-3.x, macos, virtualenv, mayavi

I'm trying to use Mayavi in my python virtual environment created with mkvirtualenv.
Mayavi package is installed into :

```
 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mayavi-4.7.2.dev0-py3.7-macosx-10.15-
 x86_64.egg/
```

In order to associate the installation of Mayavi to my virtualenv I execute this code :

```
 cd ~/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.7/sites-packages/
 ln -s /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mayavi-4.7.2.dev0-py3.7-macosx
 -10.15-x86_64.egg/  mayavi

 workon my_project
 python3
 >> import mayavi.mlab as mlab
     ---> ModuleNotFoundError : No module named 'mayavi.mlab'
```

The simlink appears to be created, by I do not understand why I'm having this issue. 
Can you help please?

Comment: You shouldn't symlink modules between Python environments. You should install modules into every environment.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that. I will make a response.

Answer (score 0):

In the light of phd's comment, I installed the Mayavi module in my specified environment using the python version associated to my environment like this :

```
$workon name_of_my_environment
$cd path_to_mayavi_directory
$python setup.py install #be careful. python is associated to the 
                         #python version installed in the 
                         #environment (check this with : which 
                         #python)
```